# Тратят ли комментарии время при выполнении кода

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

В ходе прохождения одного задания появилось предположение, что комментарий в ячейке jupyter notebook замедляет скорость ее выполнения.

Так ли это?

Есть ли способ узнать время выполнения ячейки (а не кода в ней)?

Comment: Нет, это не так.

Answer (score 0):

при компиляции комментарии игнорируется и не как не влияют на скорость выполнения